# PhoneGap 1.6 - Building a project based on an old PhoneGap version

Tags: iphone, xcode4, cordova

I am completelly new to PhoneGap (not to iOS programming) and I have from my company a project made using an old version of PhoneGap. I have installed the new PhoneGap version in my computer (v. 1.6), but the project does not build. I have noticed that the project used a file called PhoneGap.framework which can not been found in my computer. After installing the new PhoneGap v. 1.6 I have noticed the possibility to create a "Cordova-based Application" (not a PhoneGap-based application) which uses other framemork, namely the Cordova.framework.

Question: what can I do to build the project in my computer? Any kind of migration from one version to another?

I have also noticed that a project created with the new PhoneGap version creates following code slice:

```
#ifdef CORDOVA_FRAMEWORK
    #import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>
    #import <Cordova/CDVURLProtocol.h>
#else
    #import "CDVPlugin.h"
    #import "CDVURLProtocol.h"
#endif
```

but the project from my company has the following code:

```
#ifdef PHONEGAP_FRAMEWORK
    #import <PhoneGap/PGPlugin.h>
    #import <PhoneGap/PGURLProtocol.h>
#else
    #import "PGPlugin.h"
    #import "PGURLProtocol.h"
#endif
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the project has already been created using phonegap you have 2 options.

1) Upgrade the existing project to Cordova 1.6 which isn't too hard but will take a bit of time and retooling, specifically if the plugins used haven't been updated...

2) Download an older release of phonegap here and install - best version is going to be 1.3 since 1.4 is when the transition to cordova started taking place.

Here's the git for older versions - https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/tags

Installing 1.3 will let you use the original phonegap framework.

Good luck!